# Is it possible to create in Drupal a multiple pages on single page

Tags: ajax

Please check screenshot , without moving to any new URl when i click on Q&A it shows at right side the result even i can edit and save without going to new URL, everything happens on same page
Is it possible in Drupal to do that[image: img autorefresh]

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's possible, with or without Drupal. Here is the second link from [google](https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#q=drupal%20ajax%20links): [Ajaxify Drupal with JQuery Ajax](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api)

> Ajax links API module help you to load any content to a specified DIV or ajaxify whole drupal site, using JQuery Ajax. This module will also load JS for Ajax-loaded content by using Drupal.attachBehaviors(). In case you dont want to load js or css, you can alter tpl for path/node type.

Comment: Thats look grt..let me try once ..thanks Xurshid.Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

If this is a content type or [entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform), you can use install [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) with [Field Group Ajaxified Multipage](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_ajaxified_multipage) and this thing on the left can be a block ([Multipage jumplist](https://www.drupal.org/project/multipage_jumplist)).

Alternatively consider [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs).